# How to write/calculate an integral that covers $x\in\mathbb C$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Consider some function $f(x)$ defined for $x\in\mathbb C$, and it is integrate-able as well.

If I wanted to calculate the 'area' under the graph for $x\in\mathbb R$, I could use $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$.

But how would I calculate it for $x\in\mathbb C$?  I don't think there is an upper and lower bound in the normal sense, and the best I can think of is to use

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x+yi)dxdy?$$

Would that be the correct way to do it?

And if so, would it also be correct to use $\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{i\theta})d\theta dr$?

Comment: Both ways are "correct" and should produce the same result if both second integrals are defined.

Comment: @user4759923 Ok, thanks!